What Do the Seven Heads of the Beast Represent?
In Revelation 13:1-3, the Beast is described as having seven heads, with one of them appearing to have a "deadly wound" that is later healed:
Revelation 13:1-3 (KJV):

"And I stood upon the sand of the sea, and saw a beast rise up out of the sea, having seven heads and ten horns, and upon his horns ten crowns, and upon his heads the name of blasphemy. And the beast which I saw was like unto a leopard, and his feet were as the feet of a bear, and his mouth as the mouth of a lion: and the dragon gave him his power, and his seat, and great authority. And I saw one of his heads as it were wounded to death; and his deadly wound was healed: and all the world wondered after the beast."

Later, in Revelation 17:9-10, the heads are identified as both mountains and kings:
Revelation 17:9-10 (KJV):

"And here is the mind which hath wisdom. The seven heads are seven mountains, on which the woman sitteth. And there are seven kings: five are fallen, and one is, and the other is not yet come; and when he cometh, he must continue a short space."

Question
How do different Christian perspectives—historicist, futurist, and allegorical—interpret the meaning of these seven heads?

What do the seven heads represent (e.g., empires, kings, spiritual concepts)?
What might the "deadly wound" and its healing symbolize in each view?

Finally, is there reason to believe this passage suggests there will be seven iterations of Beast-like figures, with the final one ("the other is not yet come") being the ultimate Beast?
If this idea applies primarily to one group of interpretations (such as the futurist view), please explain.
Looking for an overview of perspectives on the matter. Thank you in advance. God bless.

The view given below mainly accords with what others call the "Allegorical" view, but the author states his book as being "The Resumptive Interpretation", described like this:

"With such an interpretation the book [of Revelation] applies to all
ages of the church, and all the book applies throughout those ages.
Revelation appears as a vast, unfolding, an unveiling, discovering the
great but unseen principles, the massive but invisible powers, that
lie behind the outward appearance of history, and the visible
occurrence of events.
Both principles and powers being invisible, that are depicted with
graphic imagery, stunning the imagination, in which two opposing
forces, in conflict the one with the other, range over the heavens and
the earth.
This titanic conflict takes on a variety of aspects. Hence the book
repeats the period from the ascension till the judgment over and over
again, consistently returning to the same beginning, and, from yet
another perspective, arriving at the same conclusion. This happens
seven times over.
Hence the term, 'Resumptive'. The period is resumed but under a
different standpoint. The entire age of the church appears in the
spiritual - but intangible - verities which govern it, so as to
display seven times over, from one prospect or another, seven parallel
phases of conflict between implacably antagonistic principles.
Thus, allowing for prologue, intermissions, and epilogue, the
sevenfold parallel sections of the Book of the Revelation, each
concluding with the last judgment, cover the same vast era of time,
yet in ever ascending and stupendous openings of distinctive aspects
of the same struggle." The Revelation of Jesus Christ, John
Metcalfe, pp.15-16
http://www.johnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/contact_us.htm

Given that the author has previously expounded three such 'openings', this bit might be difficult for a new-comer to pick up. Further, it is then necessary to delve into the prophetic bits of Daniel to substantiate what these seven heads collectively represent. Here are some relevant extracts:

"Chapter 13 reveals the two global concepts - depicted as powers or
authorities - by which the adversary deceives the whole world, and
challenges Christ lawfully to recover the throne and dominion which he
has usurped by spiritual wickedness.
The powers, authorities, or means by which this wickedness is
established and sustained are depicted as two beasts. This is the
allegory. Consider the first [as in the Rev. 13:1-3 quote in the
question, above]
...as always, the root lies in the Old Testament. And these precedents
are to be found in the visions and prophecies of Daniel... If these
beasts seen in vision by Daniel had not the very features combined in
the first beast of Revelation chapter 13, what else do these
descriptions convey? Even so to 'a mouth speaking great things',
Daniel 7:8, agreeing with 'and there was given unto him a mouth
speaking great things', Revelation 13:5. But there is this difference.
Daniel saw a series of figurative beasts in succession: first a
lion; then a bear; next a leopard; finally a dreadful beast having
iron teeth.
Not so the vision of the beast in Revelation 13. There is no
succession here. There is an amalgamation. In Revelation 13 the
beast is a composite... Daniel's series of beasts combine to give form
to the beast of Revelation... Now these visions are some six hundred
and fifty years apart, yet in so vast an interval everything Daniel
had prophesied had come to pass... This one beast evidently
incorporated the separate and distinct four beasts seen by Daniel,
since features peculiar to each were common to that one beast seen by
John.
But, whether Daniel or John, all arose out of the sea, that is, the
waters. "And he said unto me, The waters which thou sawest, where the
whore sitteth, are peoples, and multitudes, and nations, and tongues."
Both Daniel and John saw strange symbolic forms arise out of the
waters. The sea being in a state of turmoil, it signifies the nations,
allegorically viewed as striving without effect the one against the
other... a symbol of chaotic heaving and movement among the
multitudes, a state common to the greater part of history. But not to
all history. Ever and anon, out of such turbulent chaos, form
arises... Although Daniel saw but one beast rise after the other, John
discerns all these beasts as being various successive manifestations
of but one.
...Of these 'heads', Daniel had envisaged four... John perceives a
deeper principle; the heads might have come one after the other, they
might have appeared diverse, but behind then all lay one single
concept; the beast."[Ibid. pp.304-308]

All these snippets can do is whet your appetite to discover more. And there are about 600 more pages of exposition, starting at the beginning of Revelation, through to the end. Don't expect a short little answer to this particular beast out of the sea.
EDIT re. comment: The other verses about this beast come in Revelation 17:7-14, as quoted by the o.p. However, chapters 17 to 19 form the Sixth Opening (or, 'sixth back to the beginning' section). My answer was confined to the Fourth Opening section. To jump back and forward with verses as if on a yo-yo string is not the way to work out the immense complexity involved. A picture has to be gradually built up, like layers of washes of paint on a canvass. When that it done, eventually the full picture might be seen. But on this site, only a snippet can ever be presented to such questions. Hopefully, the 600+ page book will be read, which even the commentator will be pleased to see describes in much more detail what was supposed about the woman who sits on that beast. This question was not asking about her, though.

Well its been decoded on various Christian websites online and it is clothed in purple and scarlet, sits on seven mountains, has authority over every tribe and nation, I know you already know which institution that is.

I gave a decent answer to a similar question which happens to answer yours. See this post:
https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/101648/65291

The Beast and Seven Heads
In the context of Bible prophecy the term beast refers to a political entity or a kingdom. You can understand this from the incident in the book of Daniel where the empires of Medo-Persia and Greece are being referred to as a ram and a goat respectively. It happened as the angel foretold that a goat which referred to the Macedonian Empire, will rise and lay waste to the Persian empire.
Daniel 8:5-7

And as I was considering, behold, an he goat came from the west on the face of the whole earth, and touched not the ground: and the goat had a notable horn between his eyes. 6 And he came to the ram that had two horns, which I had seen standing before the river, and ran unto him in the fury of his power.

From the prophetic vision Daniel saw above, it can be concluded that:

A beast in a prophetic vision represents an empire, a kingdom, a governing authority led by a human being.

Now we have an idea that the beast in Revelation is a political entity/governing authority, now let's interpret the meaning of the heads. The Bible is absolutely fantastic in decoding its own terms through multiple usages in different contexts. The Bible refers to the man as the head of a marriage union, this can be interpreted to mean leader of a marriage union.
Ephesians 5:23

For the husband is the head of the wife even as Christ is the head of the church, his body, and is himself its Savior.

Now the Book of Revelation is saying that this *political entity will have seven leaders or will be led by seven kings, this shocks me because the world is divided into seven regions or continents, so it is no surprise that each continent nominates a representative to form some kind of leadership that rules the world. That is my interpretation of the seven heads.
The Deadly Wound that was healed
A new United Nations in a post nuclear apocalypse world
Since the seven continents of the world will nominate each a ruler to form this government then my understanding is that the deadly wound is collapse caused to the current United Nations by a third world war. The Bible is saying that a new United Nations will be born out of the old and lead the world as the beast.
If you doubt this interpretation ask yourself the following questions.

Why does the beast has seven kings or rulers and the world we currently live in has Seven Continents?

How is it easy for each region to nominate its chairperson as one of the seven kings?


The African union - nominates a king on behalf of Africa
The European union- nominates a king on behalf of Europe
The South American Union - nominates a king on behalf of South America
Oceania and the Asian union nominate a king on behalf of their continents
Antarctica and the North American Union does the same
And there you have an idea of who this entity will be and it is ruled by a woman or a religious institution because she rides it, but if you want more , ask a new question, stay blessed.

I guess my only “push-back”, or perhaps just follow-up, would be how would this fit with the Rev 17:9-10 passage which seems to suggest only 2 heads (or possibly 1) remains? "And here is the mind which hath wisdom. The seven heads are seven mountains, on which the woman sitteth. And there are seven kings: five are fallen, and one is, and the other is not yet come; and when he cometh, he must continue a short space."

@JacobMcDougle, after they form this global government coalition then their leader will mst probably betray them after they have pledged their loyalty to him.

Hmm... even within the context, however, this passage (especially adding in 11-13) seem to suggest more that these 7 heads/powers are iterations from past, present, and eventually into future (5 having existed prior to this prophecy, 1 existed at the time of this prophecy, and 1 is to come) with the 1 that is to come having 10 leaders/kings. Regardless, thank you for your input.

@JacobMcDougle, sure. Remember the beast is a single entity or a government and its seven heads are leaders who succeed it in ruling over it.

The view taken in my own book (which is futurist at least as regards ch7 onwards) is that the beast from the sea is an echo of the beasts from the sea in Daniel ch7, which are usually (correctly, I believe) identified as domineering political states like Babylon, the Medo-Persians, and Alexander's empire. Therefore I take that beast to represent "dominant political power".
The advantage of understanding the heads as a succession of dominant empires is that it then becomes easy enough to understand how such a head might suffer a mortal wound and come back to life. I can offer you four examples from the twentieth century alone. Imperial China; mortally wounded 1911, revived by Mao-tse-Tung. Imperial Germany, mortally wounded 1918, revived by Hitler. Imperial Russia, mortally wounded 1917, revived by Stalin, mortally wounded under Gorbachov, revived by Putin.

These 20th Century events you mention are trivial compared to the massive, global effects over the last two millenia. It is very clear that the prophecies of the apostles in regard to the Lord's return, are spiritual, deceptive, global and that they are adversarial only to those who are in the secret of the Lord. That is to say the Enemy moves through various ideologies and geo-political spheres but with one aim in mind - the elimination of competetition from the genuinely spiritual disciples of Jesus Christ.

@Nigel J I was citing them only as examples of how "mortal wound" might work.
